# How to filter JSON Data in JS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, filter

I have a of JSON Data of jobs where each job contain the following information

```
{
  jobs: [
    {
      jobseeker_create_job_id: 1,
      job_title: "Fashion Designer",
      job_description: "Fashion Designer",
      salary: "{'value': 2, 'label': 'Rs.10,001/- to Rs12,000/-'}",
      preferred_location: "[]",
      trade: "",
      trade_cat: "",
      perks: "[]",
      pia_id: 5,
      valid_till: "2020-07-22",
      note: "none",
      CreatedDate: "2020-07-22T15:49:32.120875+05:30",
      ModifiedBy: null,
      ModifiedDate: null,
      DeletedBy: null,
      DeletedDate: null,
      pia_name: "BPO Organisation",
    },
    {
      jobseeker_create_job_id: 2,
      job_title: "Fashion Designer Intern",
      job_description: "Fashion Designer Intern",
      salary: "{'value': 2, 'label': 'Rs.10,001/- to Rs12,000/-'}",
      preferred_location:
        "[{'state': {'value': 22, 'label': 'Maharashtra'}, 'district': {'value': 2821, 'label': 'Solapur'}}]",
      trade: "domain",
      trade_cat: "{'value': 17, 'label': 'FASHION DESIGN'}",
      perks: "[]",
      pia_id: 0,
      valid_till: "2020-07-22",
      note: "no",
      CreatedDate: "2020-07-22T15:51:37.256110+05:30",
      ModifiedBy: null,
      ModifiedDate: null,
      DeletedBy: null,
      DeletedDate: null,
      pia_name: "Admin",
    },
    {
      jobseeker_create_job_id: 4,
      job_title: "Test experience",
      job_description: "Test experience",
      salary: "{'value': 2, 'label': 'Rs.10,001/- to Rs12,000/-'}",
      preferred_location:
        "[{'state': {'value': 22, 'label': 'Maharashtra'}, 'district': {'value': 2821, 'label': 'Solapur'}}]",
      trade: "",
      trade_cat: "",
      perks: "[]",
      pia_id: 5,
      valid_till: "2020-07-23",
      note: "none",
      CreatedDate: "2020-07-23T12:35:01.708645+05:30",
      ModifiedBy: null,
      ModifiedDate: null,
      DeletedBy: null,
      DeletedDate: null,
      pia_name: "BPO Organisation",
    },
    {
      jobseeker_create_job_id: 5,
      job_title: "Test2 Update",
      job_description: "asd",
      salary: "{'value': 3, 'label': 'Rs.12,001/- to Rs.15000/-'}",
      preferred_location:
        "[{'state': {'value': 22, 'label': 'Maharashtra'}, 'district': {'value': 2821, 'label': 'Solapur'}}, {'state': {'value': 22, 'label': 'Maharashtra'}, 'district': {'value': 2763, 'label': 'Pune'}}]",
      trade: "",
      trade_cat: "",
      perks: "[]",
      pia_id: 5,
      is_admin: false,
      is_active: true,
      is_approve: true,
      valid_till: "2020-07-23",
      note: "none",
      CreatedDate: "2020-07-23T13:11:48.132243+05:30",
      ModifiedBy: null,
      ModifiedDate: null,
      DeletedBy: null,
      DeletedDate: null,
      pia_name: "BPO Organisation",
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to filter the JSON using preferred_location variable

```
preferred_location: "[{'state': {'value': 22, 'label': 'Maharashtra'}, 'district': {'value': 2821, 'label': 'Solapur'}}, {'state': {'value': 22, 'label': 'Maharashtra'}, 'district': {'value': 2763, 'label': 'Pune'}}]",
```

Example : If user selects solapur ( Maharashtra ) and district (Solapur)

The list should return only those jobs which contain this values in the preferred_location

I tried filtereing using job description like this

```
if (values.designation != null) {
//selected will hold the input values which user will enter
let selected = [].slice.call(values.designation).map((o) => {
return o.value;
});

// list contains JSON Data of jobs 
list = list.filter((e) => {
let designation_json = e.designation.replace(/'/g, '"');
let designation_json_decoded = JSON.parse(designation_json);
return selected.includes(
parseInt(designation_json_decoded.value)
     );
  });
}
```

I want to do the same for preferred_location variable but not able to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preferred_location` is an array inside an array of jobs, so you need a double filter

```js
const targetState = 'Maharashtra'
const targetDistrict = 'Solapur'

const jobs = [ ... your jobs array...]

const filteredJobs = jobs.filter((job) => {
  const locations = JSON.parse(job.preferred_location)
  const filteredLocations = locations.filter(location => {
    return location.state.label === targetState && location.district.label === targetDistrict
  })
  
  return filteredLocations.length > 0
})
```

Comment: Actually the state and district can contain multiple values. So what should i do in that case? And i need a seperate filter actually for state and district

Comment: the target state and the target district can be multiple? The case where there are multiple locations in the same job is already handled

Comment: Yes the target state and target district can be multiple. I can explain you more. In the front end there's a multi select for state and district. If user selects Maharashtra and let's suppose district Solpaur. He should see only those jobs matching the preferred location variable for any particular job.

Comment: You should edit the content of the second `filter` function to check multiple values, it shouldn't be hard if you know how your variables are built.